# How can I make a loopback file descriptor in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, devices

I want to be able to write data to a file descriptor then read it back later in bash.

This would look like:

```bash
# some line to create LOOPBACK_FD
echo foo >${LOOPBACK_FD}
cat <${LOOPBACK_FD}
# foo is printed
```

I know that I can use variables to store the output of commands like in:

```bash
MYMESSAGE=$(echo foo)
echo ${MYMESSAGE}
```

`memfd_create` does something *like* what I want but there'd probably be issues with the file offset and it seems bash doesn't even use it.

Maybe there's a special device that can do this?

Edit: I'm looking for a solution which doesn't require making a new node in the filesystem.

Comment: It seems you want to use a temporary file?

Comment: Does it have to be a single FD or could you use a pair of read/write FDs?

Comment: Are you looking for a named pipe, perhaps? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113986/example-of-using-named-pipes-in-linux-shell-bash)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I'm looking for something that doesn't need to have its own name in the filesystem. Two fds would work, like the two ends of a pipe. Not sure how to make an unnamed pipe besides `|` though.

Comment: One way in bash and several other shells would be `read MYMESSAGE <(echo foo)`, but I'm guessing you want the data to persist between commands in your script, and perhaps even persist after one script writes, so a different script can read a few seconds/minutes/hours later.

Comment: Pretty much everything built-in to the shell will create a file on a filesystem in one form or another (even `|` in some cases).  You may need to look into connecting to another process to PUT and GET a value that the other process stores in memory (much like Redis does).

Comment: This _will_ still create an entry in the filesystem, but check out the man page for `mkfifo`, as it sounds like an FIFO buffer ("named pipe") may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Could you say something about the problem you're trying to solve through doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> echo foo >${LOOPBACK_FD}
> cat <${LOOPBACK_FD}
> ```

That will not work -- no matter how `LOOPBACK_FD` is created or opened, or if it's accessible via the filesystem or not.

The `cat` will keep waiting for an EOF which will not come as long as the calling script (which is waiting for `cat` to terminate) will keep the writing end of the pipe open.

Something that *may* work with simple examples (but will run into deadlocks and buffering issues with anything non-trivial) is using `read` instead of `cat` to get just a line from the pipe, without trying to slurp it whole.

> Edit: I'm looking for a solution which doesn't require making a new node in the filesystem.

There are no "anonymous" pipes in Linux; even those created with the `pipe(2)` system call or with `|` in the shell are accessible via `/proc/{pid}/fd/{fd}` or `/proc/self/fd/{fd}`; they *will* always "create" a new node in filesystem.

But you can use that feature to open to writing end of an input pipe (or vice versa), which could make for an "clever" answer to your XY problem:

```
#! /bin/bash
exec {fd}< <(:) {fd}<>/proc/self/fd/$fd

echo eenie >&$fd
read message <&$fd; echo "$message"

echo meenie >&$fd
read message <&$fd; echo "$message"
```

Comment: Great answer! Stricktly speaking, you could open the pipe in non-block mode like with `zmodload zsh/system; sysopen -o nonblock -rwu fd <(:)` in zsh instead of bash. Then `cat` would work though also output some `cat: -: Resource temporarily unavailable` error message.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I think this will not close the file descriptor. `exec $fd<&-` seems not to do the trick.